# how to choose which dependency resources will be used in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resources

I have fat-jar spring boot application in jar `A.jar`
in this fat-jar I have folder `lib` with two jar files (dependencies)
let's say `B.jar` and `D.jar` in each of these jar file (B and D) we have `application.properties` (resource) which is loaded automatically during initialization of application.

Unfortunately `application.properties`from `D.jar` is loaded before `application.properties` from `B.jar`

**How to load `application.properties` from `B.jar` instead of `application.properties` from `D.jar` ?**

Answer (score 0):

Depends on location on `classpath` always first `application.properties` will be loaded. Order of jar files on `classpath` in my case (maven `pom.xml`) depends on order of registering `dependencies` in `pom.xml`

If I use

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        //B.jar
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        //D.jar
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

then `application.properties` from B.jar will be loaded.